# Golang Web App integration with NewRelic

Tags: rest, web, go, newrelic, metrics

How do I get all the metrics into APM?

I have tried the following:
https://github.com/yvasiyarov/gorelic

It does very minor insights of http, like mean response time, and not tracing external calls and all the transactions including endpoints details like Java agent.

Any resolution? Even if I have to do instrumentation in the code, what would it look like to get it into APM?

Comment: You would probably use [AddCustomMetric](https://godoc.org/github.com/yvasiyarov/gorelic#Agent.AddCustomMetric) to add the metrics you need - like external calls and time spent in SQL and such. Good luck.

Comment: @stengaard it seems like it is possible to integrate it with native newrelic sdk agent running as daemon in server + code instrumentation, though it is painful.